# In RAML, what response type (mediaType) can RAML NOT accommodate?

Tags: mule, raml

In the mulesoft training quiz, I came across the question
**

> In RAML, what response type (mediaType) can RAML NOT accommodate?

**
The correct answer is application/text.

To verify, I edited the RAML 0.8 spec, change the response MediaType to application/text, added few Inline text lines as the output, and simulated it.
I can simulate and see the output in application/text. No errors. Why is that RAML cannot accomodate MediaType application/text ?.

Answer (score 0):

Dude you can't ask questions straight out of certification exams.  Rephrase your question so that is does not include the question and answer.

Now to answer your question: RAML is for specifying RESTful APIs, IMHO you gain little by returning straight text from such an API.  You can still return "text" by wrapping the text inside JSON or XML.

Comment: Dude - Its not certification exam. Its just a quiz from training which also reveals answer at the end.  About your answer - I can specify media type application/text in RAML 0.8. It doesn't complain, so was wondering what this question is about.

Comment: Can you pass me the link please?

Comment: Oh maybe it is a dated question.

Answer (score 0):

The intent of the question is probably that `application/text` is not a valid [MIME type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).  The question is reinforcing the fact that web services described by RAML should indicate responses (along with requests) that use [standard media types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046). One of the attributes of a [RESTful architecture](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is "Uniform Interface", and using standard types makes your service conform to the uniform interface of the web.

Answer (score 0):

application/text is invalid data type .Valid types in RAML are application/xml or application/json.

mediaType: [application/json]